# "unexpected end of file" when call a foreign Library via a socket connection in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I have a C library named "libsee5.so". I am accessing it through a python code as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

This code works as expected.
Then I needed to get the same output but via a socket connection. Below screenshot shows the way I am accessing it at the server side when the client requested.

[image]

But when the client connected the code executes until libtest=ctypes.CDLL('/home/ubuntu/oracle_files/libsee5.so') then it gives the error **" line 13 of `/home/ubuntu/oracle_files/oracle_twitter': unexpected end of file
Segmentation fault (core dumped)"**

Why the same code works when execute in a script but does not work when executed via a socket connection?

Comment: Is it possible that the code from the first screenshot is ran with different user permissions? I am not sure what is the behavior of ctypes if you try to integrate with dynamic library that you don't have correct permission for, but I would check that first just in case. 
Also I doubt that it has anything to do with the fact that you use "socket connection".

Comment: I am not quite sure permission is the problem because after you pointed out that fact, I gave full permission for those files and tested. But still get the same issue.

Comment: Two suggestions: check line 13 of `/home/ubuntu/oracle_files/oracle_twitter`, and use `strace -f -v` to run the server and see what it actually does.